# Why would a cloud function fail to return when the logs report success?

Tags: google-cloud-functions

I've got a cloud function that takes about 5 minutes to run.  I need it to run many times every Monday, so I've set up a Google Cloud Scheduler job that calls it every minute.

The Cloud Scheduler logs:

```
{
  httpRequest: {}
  insertId: "1cklvxkf7jdt20"
  jsonPayload: {
    @type: "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.scheduler.logging.AttemptFinished"
    jobName: "projects/site-speed-dashboard-v2/locations/us-central1/jobs/<job_id>"
    status: "UNKNOWN"
    targetType: "HTTP"
    url: "https://us-central1-<project>.cloudfunctions.net/<function_id>"
  }
  logName: "projects/<project>/logs/cloudscheduler.googleapis.com%2Fexecutions"
  receiveTimestamp: "2021-11-02T22:03:00.584062076Z"
  resource: {
    labels: {
      job_id: "<job_id>"
      location: "us-central1"
      project_id: "<project>"
    }
    type: "cloud_scheduler_job"
  }
  severity: "ERROR"
  timestamp: "2021-11-02T22:03:00.584062076Z"
}
```

The Cloud Function logs look mostly like this:

```
2021-11-03T20:18:00.867270511Z
lighthouse-runner7jabijqjeuz1 Function execution started
2021-11-03T20:18:01.649Z
lighthouse-runner7jabijqjeuz1 Running task B
2021-11-03T20:18:01.651Z
lighthouse-runner7jabijqjeuz1 Status 1 of 5 on task B
2021-11-03T20:18:37.863Z
lighthouse-runner7jabijqjeuz1 Status 2 of 5 on task B
2021-11-03T20:19:06.586Z
lighthouse-runnervhyzz79vlmyb Saving results for task A...
2021-11-03T20:19:09.585588918Z
lighthouse-runnervhyzz79vlmyb Function execution took 308731 ms, finished with status code: 200
2021-11-03T20:19:14.866Z
lighthouse-runner7jabijqjeuz1 Status 3 of 5 on task B
2021-11-03T20:19:44.667Z
lighthouse-runner7jabijqjeuz1 Status 4 of 5 on task B
2021-11-03T20:20:15.261Z
lighthouse-runner7jabijqjeuz1 Status 5 of 5 on task B
2021-11-03T20:20:45.675Z
lighthouse-runner7jabijqjeuz1 Saving results for task B...
2021-11-03T20:20:48.338318504Z
lighthouse-runner7jabijqjeuz1 Function execution took 167472 ms, finished with status code: 200
2021-11-03T20:21:00.409847950Z
lighthouse-runner7jab3riqsqx7 Function execution started
2021-11-03T20:21:01.205Z
lighthouse-runner7jab3riqsqx7 Running task C
2021-11-03T20:21:01.206Z
lighthouse-runner7jab3riqsqx7 Status 1 of 5 on task C
2021-11-03T20:21:58.668Z
lighthouse-runner7jab3riqsqx7 Status 2 of 5 on task C
2021-11-03T20:23:05.464Z
lighthouse-runner7jab3riqsqx7 Status 3 of 5 on task C
2021-11-03T20:24:01.974Z
lighthouse-runner7jab3riqsqx7 Status 4 of 5 on task C
2021-11-03T20:25:00.416988195Z
lighthouse-runner9o59yxh9wi7g Function execution started
2021-11-03T20:25:01.608Z
lighthouse-runner9o59yxh9wi7g Running task D
2021-11-03T20:25:01.608Z
lighthouse-runner9o59yxh9wi7g Status 1 of 5 on task D
2021-11-03T20:25:08.062Z
lighthouse-runner7jab3riqsqx7 Status 5 of 5 on task C
2021-11-03T20:26:05.760Z
lighthouse-runner7jab3riqsqx7 Saving results for task C...
2021-11-03T20:26:09.605393223Z
lighthouse-runner7jab3riqsqx7 Function execution took 309196 ms, finished with status code: 200
2021-11-03T20:26:27.471Z
lighthouse-runner9o59yxh9wi7g Status 2 of 5 on task D
2021-11-03T20:27:37.853Z
lighthouse-runner9o59yxh9wi7g Status 3 of 5 on task D
```

Note that there are no errors in the log (I know that the ids don't match up, but it's a very consistent pattern).  What's happening here?

When there's no overlap (or often just *less* overlap) the function runs fine, but I don't have the throughput needed.  Running it locally there's no issue, and the function successfully returns 200 every time.

Comment: Could you specify what exactly your error is? Also, can you add a reproducible code? So that it can help the community member in understanding and answering your question. You can also check the [Troubleshooting guide for Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting) for further reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is usual. Have a look to your Cloud Functions logs:

```
2021-11-03T20:18:00.867270511Z lighthouse-runner7jabijqjeuz1 Function execution started
...
...
...
2021-11-03T20:20:48.338318504Z lighthouse-runner7jabijqjeuz1 Function execution took 167472 ms, finished with status code: 200
```

I took only these 2 lines, because they have the same executionID `7jabijqjeuz1`. Now, not the processing duration: about 2 minutes and 48 seconds.

No problem, I'm sure you increase the Cloud Functions timeout. However, the Cloud Scheduler timeout is also to 60 seconds by default, and if the Cloud Scheduler don't receive a positive ack in the delay, the run is considered as failed.

Increase the Cloud Scheduler timeout to 3 minutes (at least) to fix your issue.